# does this codeigniter code do a redirect or return html

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I was looking at the example http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#validationrules (trying to learn codeigniter) and saw this code

$this->load->view('myform');

My question is does this cause the server to send a redirect back to the user?  or does this return the user html code?

ie. I am looking to be completely REST based where a post should always redirect and never should return html(plus returning html on post screws up browsers and we have noticed the playframework model of post -> redirect -> get to work 100% of the time with browser back buttons and behaving the way a user would expect and want to keep that in place)

If the above does not redirect, anyone know of an example with validation failing that does a redirect and then displays the errors.

thanks,
Dean

Comment: it returns html code.  if you are looking to do rest, check out https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver.  you can always 'redirect()' manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$this->load->view('myform');  is a function that parse the html resource and output to the browser.

there is a redirect function in url_helper can do that.

But i just imply my function.

redirect is showing a message then redirect.

jump is jumping without a message.

message is showing a note message.

```
public function redirect($url,$message,$time=3){
    $this->template->display('common/redirect',array('url'=>$url,'message'=>$message,'time'=>$time),$this->theme,$this->thcolor,false,0);
}

public function jump($url){
    $this->template->content_display("<html><head><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url={$url}'></head><body></body></html>");
}

public function message($heading,$message){
    $this->template->display('common/message',array('heading'=>$heading,'message'=>$message),$this->theme,$this->thcolor,false,0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It loads HTML . As a general advice I would stay away from CI. It has tons of security bugs and it's not suited for your purpose. Try laravel or better rails